# fail to start mysql on CentOS7

Tags: mysql

I installed mysql in my server. But it failed to start.

The error shows here:

the `systemctl status mysqld.service` info:

```
[root@localhost run]# systemctl status mysqld.service
● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Sat 2021-05-29 10:47:55 CST; 35s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 256566 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=217/USER)

May 29 10:47:55 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
May 29 10:47:55 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
May 29 10:47:55 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
May 29 10:47:55 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service holdoff time over, sche...t.
May 29 10:47:55 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Server.
May 29 10:47:55 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for...ce
May 29 10:47:55 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
May 29 10:47:55 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
May 29 10:47:55 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

the`journalctl -xe`info:

```
May 29 10:48:00 localhost.localdomain postfix/master[21438]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/pickup pid 257074 exit status 127
May 29 10:48:00 localhost.localdomain postfix/master[21438]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/pickup: bad command startup -- throttling
May 29 10:49:00 localhost.localdomain postfix/master[21438]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/pickup pid 263057 exit status 127
May 29 10:49:00 localhost.localdomain postfix/master[21438]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/pickup: bad command startup -- throttling
May 29 10:50:00 localhost.localdomain postfix/master[21438]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/pickup pid 269083 exit status 127
May 29 10:50:00 localhost.localdomain postfix/master[21438]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/pickup: bad command startup -- throttling
May 29 10:50:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Session 2986 of user root.
-- Subject: Unit session-2986.scope has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit session-2986.scope has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
```

I tried to run `chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql`, It shows like this:

`chown: invalid user: ‘mysql:mysql’`

How can I start mysql?

Comment: what do you see anything in /var/log/messages ?

Comment: I found a message says `Failed at step USER spwaning /usr/bin/mysqld_pre_system: No such process`. Is it caused by `SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/useradd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this in few steps

1. Execute this command to check if mysql user exists: `cat /etc/passwd | grep mysql`
2. Validate if you have mysql in this file. It should look something like : `mysql:x:27:27:MySQL Server:/var/lib/mysql:/bin/false`
3. If mysql user is not present please create that user like this : `useradd -d /var/lib/mysql mysql`
4. If mysql user is present then make sure mysql user home path in `/etc/passwd` file actually exists and owned by mysql user (in the above case I mentioned `/var/lib/mysql` is home path and it has to be owned by `mysql` user)

**Note:** from what ever you have mentioned it looked like mysql user doesn't exist in your system. So it looks like creating the user with home path as `/var/lib/mysql` should solve the problem.